# Django modal forms with ajax tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, django-tables2

I am using modal forms with django ajax tables:

https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-modal-forms/

https://pypi.org/project/django-ajax-tables/

How can I update data asychronously by the modal form?
Here is some example code:

Registered Views:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'proto/index.html')

class BookTableView(View):
    model = Books
    my_table = BooksTable
    def get(self, request):
        data = self.model.objects.all()
        #filtering
        table = self.my_table(data)
        RequestConfig(request,  paginate = {"per_page": 6, "paginator_class": LazyPaginator}).configure(table)
        return HttpResponse(table.as_html(request))

class BookUpdateView(BSModalUpdateView):
    model = Books
    template_name = 'proto/books/update_book.html'
    form_class = BookModelForm
    success_message = 'Success: Book was updated.'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
```

Table:

```
class BooksTable(tables.Table):
    column1 = tables.TemplateColumn(verbose_name='Read',
                                    template_name='proto/columns/column1.html',
                                    orderable=False)
    column2 = tables.TemplateColumn(verbose_name='Update',
                                    template_name='proto/columns/column2.html',
                                    orderable=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Books
```

Column2 html template button

```
<button type="button"  class="update-book btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-form-url="{% url 'update_book' record.id %}"  onclick="updateBookModalForm()">
  <span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>
```

Close update buttons on update_book.html modal form

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" onclick="update_books_id('', '/proto/books')">
  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
...
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="submit-btn btn btn-primary">Update</button>
</div>
```

Calling ajax tables on index.html and javascript for modals :

```
...
<div class="col-12 mb-3">
   {% ajax_table "books_id" "books" %}
</div>
<script>
          function updateBookModalForm() {
            $(".update-book").each(function () {
              $(this).modalForm({
                formURL: $(this).data("form-url"),
                asyncUpdate: true,
                asyncSettings: {
                  closeOnSubmit: false,
                  successMessage: asyncSuccessMessageUpdate,
                  dataUrl: "books/",
                  dataElementId: "#books-table",
                  dataKey: "table",
                  addModalFormFunction: updateBookModalForm
                }
              });
            });
          }
          updateBookModalForm();

</script>
```

Surprisingly this works and appears assyncronouse on the frontend even not adding a books/ url, but I get a Not Found proto/books on terminal as expected.  My question is how to make the update asynchronous on the ajax table without redirecting to the homepage.  I really have tried a lot of things with the javascript function, but any modifications I make, mostly taking things out makes it break the update. Really just making the update is enough, what i want is no redirection after the update or any advice on what is the best way to go from here.

Thank you for your time.
reivaJ

Comment: Have you including `event.preventDefault();` to prevent the form from reloading the page when submitted?

Comment: Thank you ben. Ended up using `return HttpResponseNotModified()`, but will try your solution, currently rewriting jquery to use `update_table_id('', <url>)`. and pass current page.